# Displaying Query String in URL Using POST Method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm currently having some issues on figuring out how to display the Query String in the URL once a form using the POST method has been submitted..

Currently this is my ajax request and submit function:

```
function remote() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/contact.php',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: applySuccess,
        error: function(r) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(r.responseText);
            applyErrors(response.errors);
        }
    });
}

function submit(e) {

    $form.addClass('is-disabled');
    $formbutton.addClass('is-processing');
    $formcontrols.removeClass('form__control--error');
    $form.find('.form__error').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    remote();
}
```

Using the preventDefault() it prevents the page reloading and doesn't display the Query String in the URL. How would I go about retrieving the string from the header and outputting it once the form has been submitted?

I'm using a hidden form to output a specific query string and I'm tracking based off of that:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sent" name="form_sent" value="success">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to do the ajax call in the submit event not out side the submit event

Comment: Have you tried  `window.history.pushState`?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I tried moving the code for remote into the function submit, no luck, same outcome.